# Referencing a macro from worksheet to use in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which opens a dialog box to open a file, once that file is open I want to be able to use another macro on the opened file.

This is the browse file button code:

```
Sub Open_Workbook_FileDialog()

Dim strFileToOpen As String

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx* (*.xlsx*),")

If strFileToOpen = "" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
End If

End Sub
```

So the macro above allows me to open a file, once that file is opened I want to be able to use another macro on that opened file (either referenced from the same 'browse file' workbook or another workbook). Is there a way for this to happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try the code below, it should work for you according to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to run a MACRO from your opened workbook, but you had the `GetOpenFilename` filtered to show only `.xlsx` files, and you need to open `.xlsm` files (since Excle files with MACROs inside them are saved as `.xlsm`).

So your original line of:

`strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename (Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsx* (*.xlsx*),")`

was modified in the code below to:

`strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename (Title:="Please choose a file to open", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xlsm* (*.xlsm*),")`

### Code

```
Sub Open_Workbook_FileDialog()

Dim strFileToOpen As String
Dim WB  As Workbook

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

If strFileToOpen = "" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(strFileToOpen)

    Dim MacroName           As String
    ' just for example >> modify to your MACRO name
    MacroName = "main1"

    Application.Run "'" & WB.Name & "'!" & MacroName
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a small comment - if the macros are stored in the personal macro workbook, then they are available to all open worksheets afaik...

Comment: @SolarMike i don't think the PO is using an `xlsb` file, otherwise what's the entire purpose of his post ?